# Xamarin Binding List of Lists

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, binding, cross-platform

```
    public class test
    {
        public string str { get; set; }
        public List<string> lstTest { get; set; }

    }
```

This is fragment of my code, i need to **Binding** a list of this object in a **ListView**. I need **Binding** with the string **str** and the **lstTest**.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Let us know when you run into a specific issue that we can help with.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?  How do you expect to display lstTest within a single List cell?  Do you want a nested List?

Comment: So you want to use ListView which ItemsSource property will do binding to your List of type "test" and later on inside of that ListView to have another ListView that will for ItemsSource use your lstTest property of type List of type string?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use `ListView` which ItemsSource property will do binding to your `List<test>` and later on inside of that `ListView` to have another `ListView` that will for ItemsSource use your lstTest property of type `List<string>`?

You can not do that! You can not have `ListView` inside of `ListView`, however if you want you can use **ListView Grouping**, and you will have one `ListView` with all items but they can be grouped by some key, in this example (with weird naming) that can be a property called "str".

There is a lot of great tutorials and samples, but I recommend you to take a look at this one [here](https://mallibone.com/post/xamarin.forms-grouped-listview).

Comment: I have an app with this list, but i have dinamics coluns, is that the problem, but i solved with dinamyc **ItemTemplate**, in future i come to explain how i do.